# Installando ruby com rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instalador

Tenho uma duvida, eu instalei o `ruby` no ubuntu, porém foi instalado sem o `rbenv`, tem algum problema instala-lo agora, ou será necessário removê-lo primeiro?

Answer (score 2):

Robson, o ideal é você remover primeiro para se resguardar de qualquer problema de conflito entre as versões do Ruby. Deixe tudo por conta do rbev.

```
sudo apt-get purge ruby rubygems
```

Answer (score 2):

O `rbenv` é uma ferramenta bem abrangente mas muito útil quando é necessário usar várias versões em projetos diferentes, então se você não precisa disso, a instalação padrão deve te atender bem.

Answer (score 0):

Instalou via `apt install` ? Se sim! Não precisa desinstalar o que foi instalado via `apt install` .

Agora se a instalações por meio do do "RVM" é recomendado fazer a desinstalação por completo do "RMV" executando o simples comando no terminal:

`rvm implode`

ou

`rm -rf ~/.rvm`

É para instalar o rbenv que não minha opinião é muito melhor quer o RVM:
É digitar esses simples comando no terminal.

```
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
```

Depois você deve adicionar o rbenv no `$PATH` é só executar o comando no terminal.

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

e o comando para incialização do script do rbenv:

```
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

p.s: Reparar no arquivo de configuração do shell que está usando em sua máquina, ser for o `bash` é o camando acima se não e mudar para o arquivo em questão no final do comando ".bashrc" para ".zshrc" por exemplo.

Depois da instalação e só reiniciar o terminal e executar o comando:

```
rbenv install -l
```

E escolher a versão desejado pra instalar. Exemplo:

```
rbenv install 2.3
```

Pra definir a versão globalmente na máquina:

```
rbenv global 2.3
```

Pronto é executar o comando `ruby -v` é verificar a instalação.

Espero ter ajudado.